# How should I delete vector?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have a **vector**

```
std::vector<cv::Mat>* images = new std::vector<cv::Mat>();
images.push_back(image0);
images.push_back(image1);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Mat>*> allImages;
allImages.push_back(images);
```

how should I free the memory?

Comment: Why do you have a pointer to a vector? Why not simply `std::vector<cv::Mat> images`? Also, was the vector allocated with `new`?

Comment: just delete the vector. OpenCV Mat uses reference counting, so all the images are released automatically if not used otherwhere, since deleting the vector will call the destructor of each element. If the vector had cv::Mat* elements, you'd have to delete each of them manually.

Comment: Because I want that the object outlive the current scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fluent in OpenCV, but by deleting your vector, you invoke the vector's destructor which in turn invokes the destructor of all its elements.

If there is nothing special about the lifetime of `cv::Mat` (and it would be weird), just delete the vector.

Comment: it is not so uncommon that image types use some kind of handles/header and functions to manually allocate and release the pixel memory. But cv::Mat does this by reference counting and auto-release of that pixel memory.

Answer (score 0):

For c++, you can use `clear()` to free the memory of your vector and remove all objects inside. Since in your code, it is a pointer to a vector, just make sure you are clearing the vector not the pointer, it should be something like `images->clear();`.